# How to fetch keys and values from this json data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios8, nsdictionary

```
{
  "languages": "de-AT,hr,hu,sl",
  "distance": "0",
  "countryCode": "AT",
  "countryName": "Austria"
}

NSDictionary *lan = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:languages,@"lan",nil];
[lan setObject:@"de-AT"ofKey:@"languages"];
[lan setObject:@"hr"ofKey:@"languages"];
[lan setObject:@"hu"ofKey:@"languages"];
[lan setObject:@"sl"ofKey:@"languages"];

NSDictionary *dist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:@"0",@"distance",nil];

NSDictionary *code= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:@"AT",@"countryCode",nil];

NSDictionary *code= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:@"Austria",@"countryName",nil];
```

i am doing like this above , might i would be wrong or right please post your suggestions thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong.
To convert JSON to NSDictionary you should use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
    /// data = {
    //    "languages": "de-AT,hr,hu,sl",
    //    "distance": "0",
    //    "countryCode": "AT",
    //    "countryName": "Austria"
    //  }
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString * countryName = dictionary[@"countryName"]; // get countryNAme
```

For create NSDictionary like `data`

```
NSDictionary *dist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:
                      @"de-AT,hr,hu,sl",@"languages",
                      @"0",@"countryCode"
                      @"AT",@"countryCode"
                      @"Austria",@"countryName"
                       nil];
```